# 2 collections select data mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb, lookup

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        "$lookup" => array(
            "from" => $reference_2,
            "localField" => "_id",
            "foreignField" => "field_4",
            "as" => "dataref"
        )
    )
);
$results = $reference_1->aggregate($ops);
var_dump($results);
```

but there are error ?

> Notice: Undefined variable: lookup in D:\xampp\htdocs\RISET\Mongodb\mongodb_reference.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoException' with message 'zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?' in D:\xampp\htdocs\RISET\Mongodb\mongodb_reference.php:16 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\RISET\Mongodb\mongodb_reference.php(16): MongoCollection->aggregate(Array) #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\RISET\Mongodb\mongodb_reference.php on line 16

what should i do? i use mongodb 3.2.12

Comment: What is `$reference_2`. Is it a [collection object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php)? It is supposed to be a "string" with the collection name instead. See [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Also `"$lookup"` should be `'$lookup'`, note the "single quotes" `''` just like the error message actually says

Comment: try to change "$lookup" to '$lookup'

Comment: ok thank's i will try...